# How do I find out what is causing Azure B2C 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to add orchestration steps to my Azure B2C IEF user journey however, when I make changes I often times get error: "500 - Internal Server Error"

I have tried using Application Insights, but that does not tell you anything related to error 500.

Here is my Technical Profile

```
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Step1">
      <DisplayName>Step 1</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Email" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

And here is my User Journey Step

```
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Step1" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

Is there a way to find out what is causing these 500 - internal server errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ContentDefinition**: The `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` technical profile must have a `ContentDefinition` specified in the `Metadata` section. That is missing in your technical profile.

**OutputClaims**:

There is no `ValidationTechnicalProfile` in the technical profile `Step1`. That could *potentially* be an issue. Since these are `OutputClaims`, the policy must specify a way to create a value for each of those (even if at run time it may not actually get created). So an `OutputClaim` must have one of the three:

1. Specify a `DefaultValue`, which guarantees that it will have that value after the `TechnicalProfile` has been invoked.
2. Specify a `UserInputType` in the `ClaimType` under the `ClaimsSchema` section, which indicates that there is a way to retrieve that value from the user.
3. Specify it as an `OutputClaim` of a `ValidationTechnicalProfile`, which will allow another provider to retrieve such a value (e.g. from AD Graph, or a Rest API).

**CryptographicKeys**: `SelfAssertedAttributeProvider` `TechnicalProfile` also needs a `CryptographicKeys` section which specifies a key used by the provider.

I would recommend copying a technical profile from the [Starter Packs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) Github and modify those since those will contain all the required elements.

(The fact that the service is returning 500 is a bug, and needs to be fixed.)